# What happens to a cancelled download in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, download, temporary-files, private-browsing, temporary-internet-files

What happens to a download started in incognito mode when you cancel it? Does it get deleted? Or is there a temporary file somewhere?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happens when a file download is cancelled?](http://superuser.com/questions/372233/what-happens-when-a-file-download-is-cancelled)

Comment: @Moab This question is asking about Incognito mode specifically. Also the answers in that question appear to be speculation rather than fact.

Answer (score 2):

Under Windows 10, SysInternals' tool [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) shows that the temporary file is deleted (at least, in the version of Chrome I happen to be using).

It is not securely overwritten.